# Java - ArrayList with multiple int per index

Tags: java, list, arraylist

for example I have
int a =1;
int b = 2;

How can I add both values to an index of my arraylist and the be able to read them.(I need to do this in the same class where the list is)

For example with a pseudo-code i need to be able to do

```
Arraylist<integer> mylist = new Arraylist<integer> ;

int c = mylist.getnode(1).a //gets the value of a in node 1
int d = mylist.getnode(1).b //gets the value of b in node 1
```

Comment: your question is not clear, you are still living in the cloud, can you calm down and be specific what you want and give example?

Comment: If it would be possible i want it with 1D array. I want to be able to
example pseudo-code
c = mylist.getnode(1).a (gives c the value of a in the first node)
d = mylist.getnode(1).b

Comment: can you write your example pseudo code in your question ?

Comment: What you're describing should be possible with the `get` method from `List`.  Have you made any kind of attempt at this?

Comment: Seems like you want an `ArrayList<SomeClass>` where `SomeClass` contains an int a and int b.

Comment: @SeekAddo i did just now

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis problem is i do not want to take it from another class i want to be able to do this in the same class where the list is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class that contains a and b. Now create a list containing instances of that class.

```
class Tuple {
public int a, b;
}
ArrayList<Tuple> mylist = new ArrayList<>();
int a = mylist.get(0).a;
```

Comment: `Set` is a _very_ bad name for this class. First, this is not a [set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28abstract_data_type%29). Second, there already is a [Java class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) of that name. How about `Tuple` or `Pair`?

Comment: 1) Don't name a class Set. 2) Don't just plop code for an answer without any explanation.

Comment: and shoulld it not be ArrayList<integer> since i want to be able to contain 2 ints per node?

Comment: Also, you could make that class generic: `class Tuple<T> { public T a, b}`

Answer (score 0):

This is bit inefficient and has limitation for variable `index` which is bounded by the `list.size()` but here you go

```
ArrayList<HashMap> list = new ArrayList<HashMap>();
//index is where you want to place your element
if(list.size() > index){
   list.get(index).put(key, value); # in your case key = a, value = 1
}else if(list.size() == index){
   list.add(new HashMap<String,Integer>());
   list.get(index).put(key, value); # in your case key = a, value = 1
}else {
   System.out.println("Index out of bounds");
}
```

Now you can access your values:

```
list.get(<some index>).get(<some_key);
#i.e list.get(1).get("a");
```

Note: if you use above code, you can not access to random index that is out of `list.size() - 1`. `index` variable can be atmost `list.size()`

Best way to do this is to create your own class which has variables for `a` and `b`. Then create a `list = ArrayList<YourClass>();`. That is much more clean

Reason I said above code is inefficient because as I remember HashMap naively create 16 slots when you initialize it without set size, also if you cross that number container doesn't just increase it by one element, it double the size. If you know how many elements you need, you can initialize it to that number.